# calling focus() after delay() does not focus

Tags: jquery

I've created a form with `delay()` like this:

```
$('form').delay(200).fadeIn().children('input').focus();
```

That `focus()` at the end doesn't work, or even throw a console error. **Why?**

P.S. I know the *selector* isn't the issue because `.children('input').addClass('monkey')` works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently I can't focus on the input until the `delay` is over. The following makes it work as intended:

```
$('form').delay(200).fadeIn();
setTimeout(function(){
  $('form input').focus();
},200);
```

Just make the `setTimeout` delay greater than or equal to `delay()`.

Answer (score 1):

`Delay` only work with effects, use callback for setting focus.

```
$('form').delay(200).fadeIn(function() {
    $(this).children('input').focus();
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webeaccz/)

Comment: I'm unable to see `focus` input element in ur demo??

Comment: @Girish, are you sure? I'm see. What browser are you using? See this fiddle(open dev console) - http://jsfiddle.net/webeaccz/1/